# tokbox python api room creation

Tags: python, opentok

I am trying to use Tokbox for a multi-room chat, with each room having multiple routed sessions. We have developed the FE in angular to connect to our backend to retrieve a token that is generated by calling the tokbox python apis.

My questions:
1. How do implement 'rooms'. I dont see where I can pass parameters during session or token creation to pass a room?

2. How do create a 'test' room, where the user can choose and verify his camera/microphone/speaker selection? Can we create a generic 'test' room?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of sessions like a room. Anyone that is in that room will see one another. There is no way to give a name to a room, but you can keep a mapping of room name to room in some kind of storage on your server.

I wouldn't recommend creating a test room that you reuse for everyone because you could end up with lots of people seeing one another when testing their devices. I would create a separate test session for each participant.

For an example of this you can look at the [opentokdemo](http://opentokdemo.tokbox.com/) code. It's written in JavaScript (Node.js) unfortunately, not Python, but you can get an idea of how it works.

[Here](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC-V2/blob/c15a10a3d9429c70396e3511d9a1f6abfbd9a5ed/server/serverMethods.js#L330) is where they create a new sessionId for doing a network test. They create a new sessionId for every participant for them to test in.

[Here](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC-V2/blob/c15a10a3d9429c70396e3511d9a1f6abfbd9a5ed/server/serverMethods.js#L432) is where the logic is that tries to fetch the sessionId for a room name from persistent storage and if there is not one then it creates a new one and stores it.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I need to use sessions after I posted my message. For now I create sessions for each room and store the ids in the django cache if they dont exist. As for test rooms, you idea is great to just have a different session for each user. 
Thank you for the quick reply.